# Live data-binding with async function

Tags: c#, blazor

I created an async version of the counter app on Blazor:

```
<p>@counter</p>

<button @onclick="Count">Count</button>

@code {
private int counter;

private async Task Count()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("counter = " + counter);
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that the UI is not updated as the counter is incremented.
The console prints:

```
counter = 1
counter = 2
...
```

But the UI is only stays on 1 and is only updated at the end of the async function (when the counter reaches 20)

Do you know how to force the update of the UI in this context?

Comment: Henk's answer is correct.  Forget all the Task.Run junk.  Blazor WebAssembly is single threaded - Task.Run don't do anything.  Blazor Server's Synchronisation Context is designed to run everything on the single Synchronisation Context thread unless explicitly told to do so (to emulate the the WASM environment ).  Henk's answer works because `Task.Delay` yields to the Sync. Context thread, and the Renderer gets thread time to run it's queue during each iteration - which is where `StateHasChanged` queues it's render request.

Comment: In the case of an async function, why can't Blazor detect that the State has changed without explicitly calling the `StateHasChanged` method?

Comment: `StateHasChanged` is called automatically in any UI event - in this case the button click.  It gets called on the first async yield and then at the completion of the event code.  Or just once at the end if there is no async yield.  You want to update on each iteration, so you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // await Task.Run(() =>
    //{
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            counter++;
            StateHasChanged();  // signal that the UI has changed
            Console.WriteLine("counter = " + counter);
            //Task.Delay(500).Wait();
            await Task.Delay(500);    // StateHasChanged takes effect here   
        }
    //});
```

You don't need Task.Run(), and it does nothing in WebAssembly.
And never use `.Wait()`  or `.Result`. It usually deadlocks and should never be needed.

`StateHasChanged()` requests the updates and with `await Task.Delay(500);` your method becomes async and Blazor will update the UI on every step.

Comment: I finally found the documentation that discusses these details: [Synchronization Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#synchronization-context-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>@counter</p>

<button @onclick="Count">Count</button>

@code {
private int counter;

private async Task Count()
{
    // await Task.Run(() =>
    // {
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("counter = " + counter);
            StateHasChanged();
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    // });
}
```

you need to use `StateHasChanged` to update the UI, instead only the console will be updated.